# ScheduleTrigger not working CruiseControl.net 1.6

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a trigger scheduled in my Build config file. It used to work before but I noticed that it's not working since the past few days. Can anyone give a suggestion on this? Where should I check for this? This is my trigger.

```
<triggers>
    <scheduleTrigger time="21:30" buildCondition="ForceBuild" name="Scheduled"></scheduleTrigger>
</triggers>
```

Comment: This is working fine for me in version 1.6.7981.1
<triggers>
  <scheduleTrigger time="20:00" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" />
</triggers>

Comment: Where any of the answers below correct? If so, please accept one.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because the cruise control project is stopped. If it is stopped the Schedule Trigger would not work, but the intervalTrigger will.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a trigger to force the build on determined time like this.

```
<triggers>
    <intervalTrigger name="Schedule" seconds="1800" />
</triggers>
```

here it will force on every 30 minutes

Comment: Thanks. So if I add this trigger, when will the first build start?

Comment: you have to force the first build. and after that it will force automatically after 30 minutes

Comment: This worked fine! But any idea why scheduledTrigger is not working?

Comment: sorry we are using intervalTrigger thats why i suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

As per your condition , IFModification exists , then only the build will be triggered it is not explicit ,better have this done this way else it is unnesary to havea build done without any code change